# Убрать повторы строк из txt

Tags: c#

Имеется `.txt` файл, в нем есть много строк, `==` длинны, строки могут повторятся, но не по очереди: не 1-я и 2-я `==` а скажем, 14-я и 49-я строка `==`, Вопрос, как найти одинаковые строки, но вывести на экран эти `==` строки один раз, я пробовал через `Enumberble<strings>   Repeat`, но это только создало их копии..

Comment: if (!List.Contains(str)){}, но если строк очень много, с каждым новым вызовом метод будет работать медленнее.

Comment: Еще как вариант, прочитать все в list, а затем Distinct'ом получить неповторяющиеся значения. Тоже не самый быстрый способ.

Comment: @QuaternioNoir буду пробовать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для случая, когда нужно выводить на экран, немного более эффективный вариант без промежуточной материализации:

```
IEnumerable<string> allLines = File.ReadLines(path);
IEnumerable<string> distinctLines = allLines.Distinct();
foreach (var line in distinctLines)
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

или просто

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path).Distinct())
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Для случая, если нужно вывести в файл, потребуется-таки одна материализация:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    path,
    File.ReadLines(path).Distinct().ToList());
```

(иначе файл не будет закрыт при попытке записи в него).

Answer (score 3):

Напишу по шагам, чтобы было понятнее:

```
// читаем все данные из файла
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(путь);
// преобразуем в список
var list = new List<string>(lines);
// получаем только уникальные элементы
var uniqueStrings =  list.Distinct();
// записываем их обратно
File.WriteAllLines(путь, uniqueStrings);
```