# Как удалить все одинаковые строки из файла txt?

Tags: c#

Как-то спрашивал такой вопрос: [убрать повторы строк из txt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728869/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-txt)

Код оставляет уникальную строку. Но как быть если надо стереть все одинаковые строки, чтобы нигде не было повтора вообще?

**пример такой(рандомно взял символы):**

```
abcksg
p2haii
iuhjis
abcksg
```

**СТАЛО ТАК:**

```
p2haii
iuhjis
```

вроде бы понятно....

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Приведите пример, было -> стало.

Comment: @Bulson что то еще может быть не ясно ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Temp\some\out.txt",
    File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\some\in.txt")
    .GroupBy(l => l)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key));
```

Этот код вычитывает все строки, потом группирует, используя в качестве ключа саму строку (т.е. складывает одинаковые строки в кучки), потом выбирает те группы, в которых ровно одна строка. Выбирает из групп ключи группы (т.е. строки), и пишет их в файл. Порядок совпадает с порядком в первоначальной последовательности т.к. в GroupBy порядок групп соответвует порядку встречаемости первого элемента группы во входной последовательности.

Comment: @mymediaгде проблема? я прописал такой код, но он не работает!(( File.AppendAllText("откуда.txt", "куда.txt"); но чете ниче не произошло – Quarsh781 9 минут назад

Comment: Вычитывает все строки, потом группирует, используя в качестве ключа саму строку (т.е. складывает одинаковые строки в кучки), потом выбирает те группы, в которых ровно одна строка. выбирает из групп ключи группы (т.е. строки), и пишет их в файл. Порядок совпадает с порядком в первоначальной последовательности т.к. в GroupBy порядок групп соответвует порядку встречаемости первого элемента группы во входной последовательности.

Comment: @Quarsh781, а при чём тут Append?

Comment: @Qwertiy чтобы не создавать новую тему, там может быть ток одна строка должна быть, надо дописать из файла `1.txt`(не удаляя его содержимое), в файл `2.txt` в конец..

Comment: @Quarsh781, если возникла ещё какая проблема, не стесняйтесь написать новый вопрос - кнопка в правом верхнем углу, если нужен контекст, можно будет дать сюда ссылку. Только, пожалуйста, распишите подробнее, что у вас не получается.

Comment: @Quarsh781, кратко по вашей новой проблеме: чтобы применить метод [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx), нужно вначале прочитать содержимое файла-источника.

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то вот такой способ имеет право на жизнь

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
// читаем данные из файла и пишем их в словарь
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("file.txt")) // откуда читаем
{
    while(!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        string temp = file.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            dict.Add(temp, 1);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            dict[temp]++;
        }
    }
}

using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("file.txt")) // куда пишем
{
    foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
    {
        if (dict[key] == 1)
            file.WriteLine(key);
    }
}
```

Топорно очень, но работать будет.

Comment: щяс тестану).....

Comment: Вопрос не по теме, но все таки, чтобы дописать из одного файла в другой надо писать так? `File.AppendAllLines("из какого файла","в какой файл в конец дописать");` ??

Comment: Видимо комент не к тому сообщению?

Comment: а порядок строк тут нарушается

Comment: Автор не просил сохранить порядок

Comment: @mymedia на порядок строк все равно, это не важно

Comment: всё так, просто хотел обратить внимание на такую особенность решения

Comment: продублируйте комент ниже - это не к тому ответу - автор не получит уведомление

Comment: Жесть какая-то...